# c# How do you check for something that is not there

Tags: c#, if-statement, while-loop, visual-studio-2017

I have been trying to create an Othello game, but I can't seem to be able to check for a case that is not there (checking for a black token, and if it isn't there, dont do anything)

```
private void CaseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        Case allCases = (Case)sender;
        int a = 1;

        if (allCases.ColorToken == Case.Token.Nothing)
        {
            Case caseToModify;

            if (_turnIsBlack)
            {
                //Verify tokens from top to bottom
                if (Cases[allCases.Position.X, allCases.Position.Y + a].ColorToken == Case.Token.White)
                {
                    while (Cases[allCases.Position.X, allCases.Position.Y + a].ColorToken == Case.Token.White)
                    {
                        caseToModify = Cases[allCases.Position.X, allCases.Position.Y + a];
                        allCases.ColorToken = Case.Token.Black;
                        caseToModify.ColorToken = Case.Token.Black;
                        a++;
                        caseToModify.Refresh();
                        allCases.Refresh();
                        _turnIsBlack = false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I was just wondering if there was a way to check for the black token that isn't there. Doesn't need to be for this specific code, just an example of checking for something, and if it is not there, do nothing

The position is assigned with coordinates like (0,0) (1,1), the game is an 8x8 with each case being assigned a coordinate

Comment: checking for null? `if (allCases.ColorToken == null)`?

Comment: Not following here. I don't know what `Case` is and I'm not sure what your code is doing. I don't know where in this code you are checking for a black token or how that would work in your code. We are kind of coming in blind here to some very specific and context-based code without the specifics or context. Completely out of context answeR: `If (case = black ){ do something }` would be how you would check that a "case" is not black, so do nothing.I doubt that is the answer you are looking for though.

Comment: @JNevill
Case is a class created that defines the board, i didn't put in the code the checking of the token being black, because it is not even close to even working. When i check for if a case is black, it still ignores it for some reason. This would be one of the examples i have tried to check if it is black:
`if (Cases[allCases.Position.X, allCases.Position.Y + a].ColorToken == Case.Token.Black
{break;}`

Comment: If you're looking for better advice I think this question is well suited for code review stack exchange and post everything you have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's completely fine that way. These kind of statements are pretty common and although sometimes you may be able to write some fancy stuff my advice is to keep it simple unless the performance is super crucial.